# Migration from SP 2010 to SP 2013

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, migration

I have migrated one of our site from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and everything seems to be working fine, but I am facing the challenges with XSLT list view webpart and in list and libraries view. XSLT list view webpart is not rendering the data properly. I read at few blogs that SP 2013 doesn't support XSLT List view webpart.

For the list views, I can see the data properly but whenever I go to a list and try to sort or filter them then the paging stops working.

Can anyone let me know any work around or any solution for the same.

Thanks,
-Ankit

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the view

Comment: Surely SP 2013 supports XSLT Listview Webparts, MS uses them all the time themselfs

Comment: @RobertLindgren but in my case it's not working as expected. I also thought that it should work properly just after migrating the site and the re-branding needs to be done only. But nothing is working.

Comment: "Nothing is working" and "Paging stops working" is not much help I'm afraid. Can you give us some screenshots, error messages, ULS-log entries related to the issue?

Comment: sorry for the line "Nothing is working". I mean that the paging and XSLT List view webpart data rendering is not working. I will try to see in ULS-Logs if I can find something relevant.

Comment: If you go into the web part maintenace page does the Xsltlistview web part list itself as being 'Xsltlistview' or 'Xsltlistview.SharePoint.Microsoft' (not exact naming but I have got a similiar issue) I have *some* Xsltlistview features working and some not.. the question is perhaps some of them have been created with a 2007 MS feature and some with the 2010 one. I'll be interested to know.